# Returning additional default values if a condition is met

Tags: sql

I have a table with employee numbers, their jobs, their contracts and their pay rates.

I need to create a select query that lists peoples responsibility where some are the same as the job description and some have additional ones if a condition is met but which are not listed In the source DB and have different Contracts and Pay rates to the ones already listed.

Condition:  Each time an employee is a Waiter they also work as “Bar Assistant” and the Bar Assistant role is worked as a “Casual” at “8.00”

Table name Jobs:

```
Employee ID, Job, Contract, Pay rate,  
123, Waiter, Permanent, 8.15,  
234, Barista, Permanent, 9.15,  
345, Chef, Casual, 8.05,  
456, Waiter, Permanent, 9.00,  
567, Manger, Salary, 0.00,
```

The select query should give me the output:

```
Employee ID, Job, Contract, Pay rate,  
123, **Waiter**, Permanent, 8.15,  
**123, Bar assistant, Casual, 8.00**,    
234, Barista, Permanent, 9.15,  
345, Chef, Casual, 8.05,  
456, **Waiter**, Permanent, 9.00,  
**456, Bar assistant, Casual, 8.00**,  
567, Manger, Salary, 0.00,
```

I already tried a few case statement variations but they only ever return a single value.

Comment: Do you really need those ** before the id and after the rate, they just makes it messier. Apart from that I think a UNION should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
select EmployeeID, Job, Contract, Payrate
from t
union all
select EmployeeID, 'Bar assistant', 'Casual', 8.00
from t
where job = 'Waiter'
order by EmployeeId, Payrate desc;
```